# Prevent evaluation after ToExpression

Tags: notebooks

How can I produce both typesetting and evaluation of a LaTeX expression?

Illustrative example: The evaluation of `HoldForm[Sqrt[2.0]] == Sqrt[2.0]` looks ok (aside from the missing 0), but of course `HoldForm[ToExpression["\\sqrt{2.0}", TeXForm]] ==  ToExpression["\\sqrt{2.0}", TeXForm]` fails.  How can I turn the LaTeX version into similar output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that is what the third argument of ToExpression is for:

```
ToExpression["\\sqrt{2.0}",TeXForm,HoldForm]
```